# "Error: One of the parameters was invalid" from vmrun clone on VMWare Fusion 6

Tags: vmware-fusion, vmrun

I'm trying to run `vmrun clone` with VMWare Fusion 6 and seeing the following error:

```
> /Applications/VMware\ Fusion.app/Contents/Library/vmrun -T fusion clone ubuntu-12-04-3.vmwarevm/ubuntu-12.04.3.vmx foo.vmx full
Error: One of the parameters was invalid
```

This appears to be the correct syntax according to `vmrun -h`

```
> /Applications/VMware\ Fusion.app/Contents/Library/vmrun -h

clone                Path to vmx file     Create a copy of the VM
                     Path to destination vmx file
                     full|linked
                     [-snapshot=Snapshot Name]
                     [-cloneName=Name]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Credit to [@_k3rn on twitter](https://twitter.com/_k3rn/status/419250156404748289) for the answer.

`vmrun clone` only works on Fusion Professional.  You need to upgrade for this to work.